# Java connector to authenticate Sharepoint online using SAML

Tags: java, saml-2.0, sharepoint-online, office365-restapi

In my project there is a requirement to upload document from local to sharepoint online. I already done connecting to sharepoint via windows auth using the below snippet

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY),
            new NTCredentials("ID", "password", "URL", "Domain"));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build();
```

Now i need to connect to sharepoint online which have SAML/ADFSauth. So any idea guys how to connect ?

Comment: Sharepoint only supports WS-Federation. No SAML support.

Comment: @Ian I am new to SharePoint , So can you please guide me how to authenticate sharepoint which have ADFS enabled.